# How do I find the highest point in two vectors corresponing to the specificity and the sensitivity of a test?

Tags: r

I was trying to find the highest point in two vectors (e.g. the sensitivity and specificity of a test) and the solution was simply to sum them and find the maximum.

```
spec=c(.1,.2,.3,.4)
sens=c(.2,.4,.5,.4)
highest_point=which.max(spec+sens)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to solve such problems, and the solution is not unique.

The simplest approach starts by summing up the values:

```
spse <- spec + sens
```

The entries of the vector `spse` could be considered as the values of an objective function which needs to be optimized. We can proceed by searching the index that corresponds to the maximum of this objective function:

```
best <- which.max(spse)
```

In this case we have `best` equal to 89 and

```
> sens[best]
[1] 0.9159511
> spec[best]
[1] 0.4943373
```

A multitude of other definitions of the objective function are possible, such as, e.g.,

```
spse <- alpha*spec**2 + beta*sens**2
```

with `alpha > 0` and `beta > 0`. The choice depends on your preferences, i.e., on which of the measures, `spec` or `sens`, you consider more important.